# How to check values are unique in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` which has two columns and 10 rows.  When I read second column values from the `JTable`, I have to check whether those are unique values.

How to check?

Answer (score 8):

You could use a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) to determine if duplicates are being added.

```
TreeSet set = new TreeSet();

TableModel tableModel = table.getModel() ;
for(int i=0; i<tableModel.getRowCount();i++){
    Object obj = tableModel.getValueAt(i, 2);
    if(!set.add(obj)){
        //throw duplicate error
    }
}
```